# Kivy Rectangle source doesn't get updated?

Tags: python, image, kivy, updates

(I already read a lot of other posts about this but they do not seem to help me (or I simply don't understand them) )

I have a function Add() in which another function Grid() gets called that creates a Grid.png file and saves that to my desktop. This Add() function gets called multiple times (through a button) and with that also the Grid() function within. Here is a little code snippet:

```
    Width = 700
    Height = 700


    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Drw, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.CellCount = 1
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.cellAdd= int(input("\nCells to add: "))
        self.bg = ""
        with self.canvas:


            self.add = Button(text = "add", font_size =40, pos = (700,300))
            self.sub = Button(text="sub", font_size=40, pos=(700, 400))


            self.add.bind(on_press = self.Add)
            self.sub.bind(on_press= self.Sub)

            self.add_widget(self.sub)
            self.add_widget(self.add)


    def Add(self, instance):
        self.CellCount += self.cellAdd
        Grid(self.CellCount, self.Width, self.Height)


        with self.canvas:
            self.bg = Rectangle(source= r"C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Grid.png", pos=(0,0), size= (self.Width, self.Height))
            self.L = Label(text=str(self.CellCount)+" columns", pos=(500, 300))
```

What happens is that the first time I press the "Add" button, it does what it should so Add() gets called and in turn Grid() gets called and creates a new image on my desktop. Then the "bg" (background) is created and the image is correctly displayed. This only works 1 time however. After that, when I continue to press Add, nothing happens even though the Grid.png is getting changed on my desktop everytime I press "Add". The image just doesnt get updated somehow. The path always remains the same so I dont understand why it does not change the image to the new one?

I already tried to manually update the source with

`self.bg.source = r"C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Grid.png"`

but that does not do anything. I am pretty new to Kivy so I apologize if this gets asked alot.

Thank you for reading!

**EDIT**
I fixed it with this:

```
    def Add(self, instance):

        self.CellCount += self.cellAdd
        Grid(self.CellCount, self.Width, self.Height)

        with self.canvas:
            self.canvas.clear()
            self.bg =Image(source= r"C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Grid.png", pos=(0,0), size= (self.Width, self.Height))
            self.bg.reload()
        self.L = Label(text=str(self.CellCount)+" columns", pos=(500, 300))
```

I still dont know why Cache.remove() doesnt work as it seems logical to me but at least .reload() works good enough. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Does inserting a `clear()` command in the `canvas` before you add the `bg` and the `Label` help?

Comment: @JohnAnderson Nope I tried that. Added a ```self.canvas.clear()``` below ```with self.canvas: ``` but it doesnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

Probably the image source is being cached by Kivy's image loader, so you need to inform it of the update. Try `from kivy.cache import Cache` and `Cache.remove("kv.texture", your_filename)` (or omit the `your_filename` argument to clear the whole texture cache).

Comment: I actually thought this would be the solution now as it seems logical, but it still does not work...I am stumped. I inserted the ```Cache.remove("kv.texture" ) ``` (also imported kv.cache) before the Grid() call but it still doesnt work. I also tried with other categories like "kv.image" or "kv.graphics".